# how i makes decrement value stop at zero

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xampp, disabled-input, tabstop

I am a beginner in xamarin android and I try to develop a simple app in xamarin android that makes decrement value into zero only ... but when I am trying the decrement value  is continue to the negative value I cant makes it stop at zero value

how I can make decrement value stop at zero?

```
enter code here   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    int txt3;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1); 
        txt3 = 5;
        textView1.Click += delegate
        {
            textView1.Text = (txt3--).ToString();

        };
    }
}
```

}

when I run the app the value are 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 ...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  textView1.Click += delegate
{
    result = text3--;
    if (result < 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    textView1.Text = (result).ToString();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are decrementing the value without checking whether it reached below 0 and that is why it is going to negative values. You can try

```
if(0 < txt3)
{
   txt3 = txt3 - 1;
   textView1.Text = Convert.ToString(txt3);
}
```